# Filling Nan using pandas using column same values

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas what I am doing is my Column name TESTCASE have the Testcase names there is a major time delay between Testcase 1 to test case 4 I want ti fill the table with Nan at that place

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhJxg.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here are some suggestions. 1)Some of us have trouble viewing images. Could you edit your question and place your Python code in place of the image, please? 2) What are the conditions that you wanted to put in a NaN? 3) What Python code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to fill the missing values with NaN, it will be done automatically. To confirm this you can run the command below:

`df.columns[df.isnull().any()]`

This will display all columns with missing values.

To select the rows with missing values in the TESTCASE column, run the command below:

`df[df['TESTCASE '].isnull()]`

Comment: no Sheila, if you see clearly every 5 sec one new data is getting added if the data is not added in 5sec I want one row of nan to get printed